# c GTK g_signal_connect using the data field

Tags: c, gtk3

With g_signal connect, I'm trying to pass a parameter that is a simple character 'S' using the "data" field.

???(I think I understand that the field is not for data, rather its for a pointer to the data.)???

Anyway, I have code like this:

```
g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT(b_save), "clicked", my_test, (gpointer) 'S');
```

calling code like this:

```
void my_test(GtkMenuItem *menuitem, gpointer data)
{
  printf("Pointer variable contains: %p\n", data);
}
```

I'm not sure if my_test should accept two parameters or one?
I'm not sure how to printf the pointed to value 'S'.
(In my called function my_test how do I get at the 'S'?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`'S'` is a character *constant*. Unlike string literals, character constants aren't addressable, they are just a number in disguise. So the data parameter in your callback doesn't contain a pointer to `'S'` (no more than it could contain a pointer to the constant `1`), but instead is the value of the constant reinterpreted as a `gpointer`.

If your C implementation guarantees the 1-to-1 mapping between integers and pointers, you can keep your setup, and have your callback print like this:

```
printf("Data variable contains: %c\n", (char)data); // char and NOT char*
```

If you want to pass addresses, then you need to pass the address of some storage. More importantly, storage that won't expire before the callback is executed. Dynamically allocating the memory is probably best, but you can pass the address of a static variable as well:

```
static char data = 'S';
g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT(b_save), "clicked", my_test, &data);
// ...
printf("Data variable contains: %c\n", *(char*)data); // Now data is a pointer to a single character.
```

Comment: I still haven't sorted it out.Does my_test receive one or two parameters?

Comment: I still haven't sorted it out. OK I put in: static char data = 'S' and used &data in the call. Does my_test receive one or two parameters? How should it look?  And the line printf("Data variable contains: %c\n", (char)data); produces a compiler error: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast].

Comment: @GraemeJensz - I presented two exclusive options. You either keep passing a constant, or you pass an address. If you pass an address to a character, then treat it as such (I updated the answer). If you pass the character value itself (after casting to a pointer), you need to cast it back to a character. To get rid of the warning, do an intermediate cast to `int` or `long` before casting to `char` (i.e. `(char)(int)data`).

Comment: Still lost... I'm going with your option that has: static char data = 'S'; and then a call using &data.
Does my_test accept one or two parameters??? How are it's parameter(s) set out???
Do I get the 'S' printed out by using printf("And the passed param is: %c\n", (char)(int)data); ???

Comment: @GraemeJensz - Why would there be two parameters all of a sudden? The callback is specified to accept one. The reinterpreting of types is on you. Your problem is completely disjoint from using GTK. [Here's an example to demonstrate the concepts](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/941f50b6f9c10f83). If you are still lost, then you need to go over C basics once again. The scope of an explanation is well beyond a simple Stackoverflow answer.

Comment: OK I've got it now! The example to demonstrate the concepts worked for me.